# How would I use a bot to send multiple reactions on one message? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is kind of a dumb question but how would I make a discord.py event to automatically react to a message with a bunch of different default discord emojis at once. I am new to discord.py

Comment: Can you show where you got so far?

Comment: Thats the thing, im not too sure where to start :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the message object somehow, `ctx.message` is one way after that use.

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="")
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⚠️")
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="")
```

You can get the emoji using `\⚠️` in discord and then copy past it, above is some random examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on_message` event. Its a default `d.py` function. It is an automatic function.

Comment: Consider adding a code example to prove this works to verify your assumptions.